# I think there's something wrong with the tense in this sentence.

Tags: tenses

The sentence:

> Two of the three crew members are killed, one of whom dies later in
>   hospital.

There are initially three people, and two of them are dead. Let's call them A and B. Let's say B dies later. Then the sequence of event goes like this.

Plane crashes -> A dies -> B dies in the hospital.

To describe this sequence of events, I would say:

> Two of the three crew members were killed; one of whom have died later
>   in hospital.

because there's a need to differentiate the time of each death, but I'm not too sure if I have achieved it correctly. I would argue that the first sentence is wrong because the later clause indicates the present, which clearly does not make sense.

Comment: There have been a number of questions on this site concerning use of ["the historical present"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250707/how-to-distinguish-if-a-sentence-is-using-the-historical-present). May I suggest you refer to them for further guidance.

Comment: I agree that present perfect (“have died”) is inappropriate in this context — but, if you were to use it, you should say “one of whom ***has*** died”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/List_of_notable_accidents_and_incidents_on_commercial_airliners) appears to be the source for the sentence in question.

It is a "List of notable accidents involving commercial aircraft": by genre, a ***chronicle***. It is expressed, as is conventional for a chronicle, entirely in the present tense, as if the events it narrates were unfolding  in 'actual' time, before the reader's eyes.

Comment: If this was not a chronicle, then how should I write this sentence?

Comment: @VladeKR Possibly: “Two of the three crew members were killed in the accident: one was killed immediately and the other died later in hospital.“ Don’t use the perfect for the simple past *died*.

Comment: @VladeKR *On May 27, 2017, Summit Air Flight 409, a Let L-410 operating a cargo flight, **crashed** short of Lukla Airport, Nepal in poor visibility. Two of the three crew members **died**, one in the crash and another later in hospital.*